# Show that there is some number c in the set [1,2] for which 2f(c)=f(2c).

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Need some help with this problem, I understand the basic concepts behind what the question is asking but have no idea how to begin coming up with an answer. I am fairly certain that somehow I use the Intermediate Value Theorem?
Thank you in advance!

> Suppose $f(x):[1,4] \to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function and $f(1)=3$ and $f(2)=4$ and $f(4)=10$. Show that there must be some number $c$ in the set $[1,2]$ for which $2f(c)=f(2c)$. (You need to consider the properties that continuous functions have and construct the appropriate continuous function).

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(x)=f(2x)-2f(x)$ and evaluate $g(1)$ and $g(2)$ using the given values.

Comment: So if i define g(x) as you did then I would want g(x)=0 for all c in the set [1,2] but how do I define c that way, what about constructing the appropriate continuous function?

Comment: No, you want to show the existence of **at least one** $c \in[1,2]$ with $g(c)=0$.